# Criar alias para colunas de uma tabela no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

É possível criar alias para o nome das colunas de uma tabela no usando o Model do Laravel? Exemplo: tenho uma tabela `questao` com as colunas:

```
id
questao
disciplinas_id
serie_id
professor_id
```

Ficaria mais simples se eu pudesse tratar as colunas por outros nomes dentro da aplicação. Chamar `professor_id` de `prof`, por exemplo. Dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse. Alguém sabe se o Eloquent permite isso? Se sim, como fazer?

Comment: Pelos exemplos que vi ao pesquisar, é possível fazer isso utilizando essa solução - https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Mappable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mais fácil que isso, você pode, no seu `Model`, utilizar [*accessor*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) e [*mutator*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) para definir o atalho. Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questao extends Model
{
    public function getProfAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['professor_id'];
    }
}
```

Neste caso, ao acessar o valor de `$questao->prof`, o método `getProfAttribute` é chamado retornando o valor do atributo `professor_id`. Já, para atualizar o valor através do atalho, é preciso definir o *mutator*:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questao extends Model
{
    public function setProfAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['professor_id'] = $value;
    }
}
```

O que lhe permite fazer algo como `$questao->prof = 3`.

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigada!